# Invoking GET statuses/user_timeline with user_id='' seems to invoke GET statuses/home_timeline. Why?

Tags: api, twitter

As I was trying to harvest the `user_timelines` for a list of `user_id`s, I noticed that my own home_timeline was also being harvested. In the end I discovered that whenever my list used a null string entry for user_id, executing the code below was the same as executing
`twitter_api.statuses.home_timeline`. That is ok, but I do not see such behavior Twitter- documented? What am I missing in the documentation?

```
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
twitter_api.statuses.user_timeline(user_id='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - if you invoke the Twitter API v1.1 `user_timeline` method without a `user_id` or `screen_name` parameter specified (or null), it will return the `user_timeline` for the authenticated user making the API call. This is undocumented behaviour.

Note that `home_timeline` is a different method, and will return Tweets from the users you follow, not your own Tweets. I think you're describing the former (`user_timeline`), not `home_timeline`.

I'll make a note to get this added to the official API documentation.